# The 6th hard drive is smaller than the actual size in Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: server, hard-drive

Ubuntu 14.04 Server:

I have installed 6x2TB drive on a DELL server. Only the first 5 are recognized as 2TB. the last one only shows 100G.

The problem is not a hardware problem. Since when using Ubuntu 12.04, all drives are recognized.

Any idea why or solution..

Here's the output of sudo parted -l::  the disk with the problem is sdf

```
Model: DELL PERC H710P (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 1979GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  100GB   100GB   primary  ext4         raid
 2      100GB   300GB   200GB   primary               boot, raid
 3      300GB   1979GB  1679GB  primary               raid


Model: DELL PERC H710P (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1979GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  100GB   100GB   primary  ntfs         raid
 2      100GB   300GB   200GB   primary               boot, raid
 3      300GB   1979GB  1679GB  primary               raid


Model: DELL PERC H710P (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 1979GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  100GB   100GB   primary  ntfs         raid
 2      100GB   300GB   200GB   primary               boot, raid
 3      300GB   1979GB  1679GB  primary               raid


Model: DELL PERC H710P (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 1979GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  100GB   100GB   primary  ntfs         raid
 2      100GB   300GB   200GB   primary               boot, raid
 3      300GB   1979GB  1679GB  primary               raid


Model: DELL PERC H710P (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 1979GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  100GB   100GB   primary  ntfs         raid
 2      100GB   300GB   200GB   primary               boot, raid
 3      300GB   1979GB  1679GB  primary               raid


Model: DELL PERC H710P (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdf: 104GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start  End  Size  Type  File system  Flags


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md0: 300GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  300GB  300GB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md1: 600GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  600GB  600GB  ext4


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md2: 5037GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  5037GB  5037GB  ext4
```

Comment: Does this problem also happen if you boot from another OS (perhaps from a live USB)?

Comment: No. It's specific for Server 14.04.   I installed 12.04 and all drives are recognized with 2TB.